# Mutating a void returning Java object

Tags: clojure

Im lost at how to best translate the following Java code to ideomatic Clojure

```
        var lsClient = new LightstreamerClient(...);
        lsClient.connectionDetails.setUser(...);
        lsClient.connectionDetails.setPassword(...);
        lsClient.addListener(...);
        lsClient.connect();
```

I have tried multiple things and have ended up with something that does not even compile

```
(defn create-connection-and-subscriptions!
  [{:keys [identifier cst token ls-endpoint]} callback]
  (let [password (str "CST-" cst "|XST-" token)
        client (LightstreamerClient. ls-endpoint nil)
        connection-listener (client-listener-adapter/create callback)]
    (doseq [c [client]]
      (.setPassword (.-connectionDetails c) password)
      ( .setUser (.-connectionDetails c) identifier)
      (.addListener connection-listener c)
      (.connect c))
    ))
```

How should I change this for things to work as the Java code. OBS `...` in java code is just that I have have removed the input.

Comment: Try using [`doto`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/doto)

Comment: That will not work with the .-connectionDetails since client will not be the last argument to that form?

Comment: Is there any running Lightstreamer server for connection testing (with some existing user + password), so we don't have to set up our own?

Comment: Dont see how that is relevant to the question?

Comment: As was mentioned doseq is the wrong construct. You really shouldn't need that closure. What errors are you getting in the REPL if you try and run the 4 lines inside one by one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've written is weird (why `doseq` over a single item?), but should work. I'd replace `(doseq [c [client]]` with `(let [c client]` if you want to do it that way, or just rename the existing variable to `c`.

If you want to avoid re-typing the variable name, then `doto` is the tool for performing multiple side-effecting effects with the same first argument. It's not super clear that this is worth it for objects you only call two methods on, but you could write

```
(doto (.-connectionDetails client)
  (.setPassword password)
  (.setUser identifier))
(doto client
  (.addListener connection-listener)
  (.connect))
```

If you are truly devoted to doing it all as one expression with no new variables, and don't mind some labyrinthine macro rewriting, you can write this instead:

```
(doto (LightstreamerClient. ls-endpoint nil)
  (-> (.-connectionDetails)
      (doto 
        (.setPassword password)
        (.setUser identifier)))
  (.addListener connection-listener)
  (.connect))
```

I find this rather cute, but code should be written to be readable, not cute, so I don't recommend it. You may enjoy puzzling through how it works, though.